# IIS URL Rewrite to not pass the .htm into the rewrite

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I have an IIS server with many domains multihomed. I have base rewrite rules for seo friendly URLS.

Example:

*www.something.com/here-is-the-page*

current converts to

*www.something.com/index.htm?pagetitle=here-is-the-page*

Problem is that one domain needs this rule to allow the URLs to read with .htm on the end.

Example:

*www.something.com/here-is-the-page.htm*

needs to convert to

*www.something.com/index.htm?pagetitle=here-is-the-page*

(note, just removed the .htm, although I still want the .htm to display in the location bar)...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for all of the assistance...[sarcasm] below is the solution.
The key here is the MatchAll.

Look at the URL

Check to see if this is for www.something.com

Check to make sure there is not an actual file with the filename.htm

Check there is no directory with that name

If the file is sitemap.htm (which does exist, then do not process) This should be caught by the previous check for file, but just got added for overkill. Since this is a rewrite and not a redirect the .htm will remain displaying in the navigation bar.

```
<rule name="remove the htm" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="([_0-9a-z-]+)\.htm$" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.something.com)$" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="sitemap\.htm$" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.cfm?pagetitle={R:1}" />
</rule>
```